# Solving a Bessel-like equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues for a Schrödinger's equation in a potential that looks like

$$ V(\ell) = \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\left(\alpha e^{-\ell}-(\alpha+1)\right)^2 - (\alpha+1)^2\right).$$

So that I'm trying to solve something like

$$ -f''(\ell)+V(\ell)f(\ell) = Ef(\ell) $$

After substituting $r=e^{-\ell}$, my eigenvalue equation looks like

$$-r^2\Psi''(r)-r\Psi'(r) + \left[\left(\alpha r-(\alpha+1)\right)^2 - (\alpha+1)^2  +  \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - E \right]\Psi(r)=0
 $$

which looks quite a lot like a Bessel equation, but I'm kind of lost after this. I tried substituting $x  =\alpha r - (\alpha+1)$, but then I'd lose the Bessel-like derivatives on the first two terms.

I am chiefly interested in energies $E<\left(\alpha+1/2\right)^2$. I know that the first eigenvalue is $E=0$ and I know the solution, and I am really only trying to find the gap with the second eigenvalue.

I would appreciate any hints into what I can do to solve this.